# Passing values though the submit button?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, submit

I am trying to pass values thought the submit button of a form.

These are the values i need:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload() //string token, string filename, string moddate, object file
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters.Add("Token", token);
                parameters.Add("FileName", filename);
                parameters.Add("ModDate", DateTime.Today.ToString());
                parameters.Add("File", file);

            String compleat = "Complete";  
            return View(compleat);              
        }
```

This is where i try get the values:

```
<form action="/Home/Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
@string token = @Model.Token;
@string fileName = file.tostring();
@File actualfile = file;
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

I would like to do something like this, my JavaScript is probably wrong as i am new to it.

After the submit is clicked how can i access the variables from the home controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC you want to work with viewmodels. There is also html.beginform helper to use so your code won't look so messy.

UploadViewModel.cs

```
public class UploadViewModel
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ModDate { get; set; }
    public object File { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
    public ActionResult Upload()
    {
        TempData["Status"] = "";
        return View(new UploadViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewModel upload) //string token, string filename, string moddate, object file
    {
        //*** Do something with the upload viewmodel

        // It's probably a good idea to store the message into tempdata
        TempData["Status"] = "Complete";
        return View();
    }
```

Upload.cshtml

```
@model UploadViewModel

@Html.Label(TempData["Status"].ToString())
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Token)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Token)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ModDate)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ModDate)
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FileName)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FileName)
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

This is pretty basic stuff, you should read up some tutorials. Like these: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials